# [Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/sqlncli/lib64/libsqlncli-11.0.so.1790.0' : file not found

Tags: sql-server, linux, odbc

I have installed Oracle Linux 6.5 64 bits and I want to connect with MSSQL Server using ODBC.
I have installed unixODBC and then Driver Manager and I didnt have any problem.
I created a DNS in odbc.ini file, and I have setup my odbcinst.ini

SUCCESFULL MESSAGE AFTER INSTALL DRIVER MANAGER

```
[root@MV-OBI-LINUX sqlncli-11.0.1790.0]# odbcinst -q -d -n "SQL Server     Native Client 11.0"
[SQL Server Native Client 11.0]
Description=Microsoft SQL Server ODBC Driver V1.0 for Linux
Driver=/opt/microsoft/sqlncli/lib64/libsqlncli-11.0.so.1790.0
UsageCount=4
Threading=1
```

FIRST ERROR

```
[root@MV-OBI-LINUX sqlncli-11.0.1790.0]# isql -v msPreflex userbd grup0r0c10
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/sqlncli/lib64/libsqlncli-11.0.so.1790.0' : file not found
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

SECOND ERROR

```
[root@MV-OBI-LINUX sqlncli-11.0.1790.0]# sqlcmd -$172.16.1.141 -userbd -grup0r0c10
sqlcmd: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

ODBC.INI

```
[msPreflex]
Driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0
Description=Prueba Preflex
Trace=Yes
Server=172.16.1.141
Port=1433
Database=Preflex
```

ODBCINST.INI

```
[SQL Server Native Client 11.0]
Description=Microsoft SQL Server ODBC Driver V1.0 for Linux
Driver=/opt/microsoft/sqlncli/lib64/libsqlncli-11.0.so.1790.0
UsageCount=4
Threading=1
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center. Better suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com/, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /usr/lib64
ll libodbcinst.so.1 libodbc.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Nov 23 11:34 libodbcinst.so.1 -> libodbcinst.so.2.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Nov 23 11:20 libodbc.so.1 -> libodbc.so.2.0.0
```

Is very important this links exist in /usr/lib64
but links depend from version of your odbc package